# Passing positional arguments (specifying columns) to awk interpreter

Tags: awk

With the following awk script I am calculating the numerical derivative of numerical data:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR==1{x=$2;y=$3}
# forward derivative for the first record and store values:
NR==2{yprime=($3-y)/($2-x);xs=x;xi=$2;ys=y;yi=$3;print x, yprime}
# central derivative (for the previous record)
NR>2{yprime=($3-ys)/($2-xs);print xi, yprime; xs=xi;xi=$2;ys=yi;yi=$3;}
# backward derivative for the last record:
END{yprime=($3-ys)/($2-xs); print $2, yprime;}
```

Example data looks like:

```
050 -0.482 2.7005 2.7214 0.33 0.33256 1.0254 0.0095323
049 -0.48 2.6891 2.9106 0.33403 0.36155 1.114 0.01061
048 -0.47 0.72628 2.4895 -0.11639 -0.39894 0.89014 0.007514
047 -0.46 0.014188 0.12513 -0.32694 -2.8834 0.71609 0.0011619
046 -0.45 0.0069401 0.06229 -0.3289 -2.952 0.70036 0.00050154
045 -0.44 0.0051829 0.046877 -0.32881 -2.974 0.6922 0.00052942
044 -0.43 0.0044612 0.04055 -0.32848 -2.9857 0.6872 0.00025896
043 -0.42 0.0040918 0.037534 -0.32721 -3.0014 0.68384 0.00037138
042 -0.41 0.0039 0.036017 -0.32622 -3.0126 0.68058 0.0005044
041 -0.4 0.0037711 0.035516 -0.32308 -3.0428 0.67944 0.00061384
040 -0.39 0.0037183 0.035386 -0.32141 -3.0588 0.6771 0.00065571
039 -0.38 0.0037 0.035641 -0.31945 -3.0772 0.67461 0.0007741
```

Running

```
./numdiv.awk file.dat
```

I'd like to change my script so that I can specify column numbers as positional arguments (here $2 and $3). Awk seems to have the special variable `ARGV` which could be used for it.

Comment: So you want to be able to use `NR==2{yprime=($ANOTHER_ROW-y)` instead of `NR==2{yprime=($3-y)` and set this ANOTHER_ROW value?

Comment: yes. Sorry that it wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: ARGV[] is the array of arguments, which should almost always be simply file names. To set awk variables from the command line you'd use `awk -v awkvar=value '...script...' files`, except in rare cases where you'd use an alternative approach. If that doesn't help, update your question to clarify what you're trying to do with expected output as well as your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-v` option to pass arguments to awk.

See an example:

```
$ cat a
hello
i am here
but you are there

$ awk -v row=2 '{print $row}' a

am
you
```

In your case, you could for example replace

```
NR==2{yprime=($3-y)/($2-x);xs=x;xi=$2;ys=y;yi=$3;print x, yprime}
```

with

```
NR==2{yprime=($second_col-y)/($first_col-x);xs=x;xi=$first_col;ys=y;yi=$second_col;print x, yprime}
```

And call the script with:

```
awk -f your_script.awk -v first_col=2 -v second_col=4 file
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a shebang line in the awk script and make it executable?

Comment: You do not need to use a shebang line to have an executable shell script that calls awk. It's a bad habit.

Comment: I understand. It was a question whether this possibility exists.

Comment: That would be a shell question, not an awk question, and you only tagged this with awk so shell experts won't be looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this shell shebang construct to invoke awk from your shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
script
```

Don't. It makes your shell script infinitesimally briefer at the expense of flexibility in calling awk. Change it to:

```
/usr/bin/awk '
script
' "$@"
```

and then you can solve your problem just by using awks `-v` option to set awk variables, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v col=3 '
{ print $col }
' "$@"
```

By the way - do NOT use /usr/bin/awk if you're on Solaris as that is old, broken awk. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead (or even better install and use gawk).

Comment: Ok I didn't know that I loose flexibility by using #!/usr/bin/awk -f. I will follow the answer by fedorqui and pass the script as an option to awk (using a shell as wrapper would also be possbile but not necessary). Thank you.

Comment: OK. Not sure why you wouldn't just change `#!/usr/bin/awk -f script` to `/usr/bin/awk 'script' "$@"` and continue to use it as-is but whatever works for you....